# How to get the id of created record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, supabase

I am creating a Supabase based app. The frontend is NextJs and the backend is Rails.
All works, but the issue is that when I create a record in Rails I don't get the created object back (which I do in Javascript/Nextjs).

I tried this but it made no difference:

```
def create_job(project_id, type)
 output = HTTParty.post(@base_url + "openai_jobs?select=*", headers: headers, body: 
 body_job(project_id, type))
end
```

Comment: `when I create a record in Rails I don't get the created object back` what do you mean?

Comment: There is an insufficient amount of information here to assist in any fashion.